# htaccess redirect from https getting 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect from either http or https to a new website.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
Redirect /abc https://www.newdomain.com/abc
```

This works- http://www.olddomain.com/abc

But this gets a 404- https://www.olddomain.com/abc. The

Answer (score 0):

You should use a rewrite since you're already using mod_rewrite and it should go before your other rules. If you are redirecting to a new domain, the other rules probably don't need to be there anymore any.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#redirect to new domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#other rules you probably do not need anymore
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't think I explained well enough in my original. There are only a few pages that are redirecting to the new site not the entire old site. I'll try your solution and just change add a rewriterule for each page.